apiRequestContext.get: Invalid URL error during playwright tests
I have problem with making API request in my playwright project.
Here is example of code
const { test, expect, request, chromium } = require('@playwright/test');

test('API request with browser automation', async ({ page }) => {
    // Launch the browser
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();

    // Correctly formatted URL with "https"
    const apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
    console.log('Making API request to:', apiUrl);

    // Perform the GET request
    const apiResponse = await context.request.get(apiUrl);

    // Check the response status
    expect(apiResponse.status()).toBe(200);

    // Parse and log the response body
    const apiResponseBody = await apiResponse.json();
    console.log('API Response:', apiResponseBody);

    // Validate response data
    expect(apiResponseBody).toHaveProperty('userId');
    expect(apiResponseBody.userId).toBe(1);
    expect(apiResponseBody).toHaveProperty('title', 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit');
    expect(apiResponseBody).toHaveProperty('body');

    // Optionally interact with the browser
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    const title = await page.title();
    console.log('Page Title:', title);

    // Clean up: close the page and browser
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
});

I see that if I have test in  main catalog of project, the test finishes with success,
but when file is in subfolder
x/y/z/a/apiTest.spec.ts I see error:

TypeError: apiRequestContext.get: Invalid URL',

(also when I add just a string to line const apiResponse = await context.request.get('myUrl');)
What am I missing/doing wrong?

Best not to launch/close browsers and contexts in each test. Let PW manage that for you and use the provided page fixture. Beyond that, the test looks fine regardless of which folder you're running this from. Then again, the require import is unusual. Usually use modules. Are you running this with npx playwright test or some other command?

context.request object is specific to the Playwright APIRequestContext, and it might not be initialized properly when moving files across directories. Ensure you are correctly calling request.newContext() before making the request, const apiRequestContext = await request.newContext();
const apiResponse = await apiRequestContext.get(apiUrl)
